# Confluence REST API request while not being admin ends in 401 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jira, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am developing confluence blueprint where a user can choose between jira projects and use them for specific jira issues report.

Both instances are connected correctly with each other and I get results but only if I am logged as an admin. With normal user I am getting this:

```
<status>
   <status-code>401</status-code>
   <message>This resource requires WebSudo.</message>
</status>
```

Unfortunately I have to get the information from the jira server as AJAX post request with JavaScript and here is my code:

```
function pickDate(e, state) {
    AJS.$('#spLebenStart').datePicker({
        overrideBrowserDefault: true
    });
    
    getJiraUrl();
}

function getJiraUrl(){
    var appUrl = AJS.contextPath() + "/rest/applinks/1.0/applicationlink/type/jira";
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: appUrl,
        data: {
            key: "value"
        }, 
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml){
            jiraID = $(xml).find("id").text();
        },
        complete: function(){
            getJiraProjects(jiraID);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("ERROR @ getJiraUrl");
        }
    });
}

function getJiraProjects(applicationId){
    var restUrl = AJS.contextPath() + "/rest/applinks/1.0/entities/"+applicationId+"?os_authType=any";
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: restUrl,
        data: {
            key: "value"
        },
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml){
            jiraProjectKeys = [];
            $(xml).find("entity").each(function(){
                jiraProjectKeys.push({id: $(this).attr("key"), text: $(this).attr("name")});
            });
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("ERROR @ getJiraProjects");
        },
        complete: function(){
            AJS.$('#spSelect').auiSelect2({
                placeholder: 'Projekt auswählen...',
                data:jiraProjectKeys,
                multiple: false
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried to use login information with basic authentication in AJAX but it didn't help. Of course I can hardcode the id in the code but what if it get changed? Its not the best solution imo. How can I manage the websudo problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new here (as a contributor) so pardon my newbie bloopers.

Looks like accessing `/rest/applinks/1.0/applicationlink/type/jira` indeed requires admin permissions. But there's an undocumented (AFAIK) workaround and this is how I do it.

There's an Atlassian plugin called `Confluence JIRA Plugin`. It's bundled with Confluence (hence it should be available in your installation). It provides you with a few cool features allowing JIRA integration (e.g. JIRA and JIRA Chart macros). To provide the integration it also adds a few useful endpoints to your Confluence REST API (which don't require admin access):

1. `/rest/jiraanywhere/1.0/servers` or `/rest/jira-integration/1.0/servers` to list the linked JIRA servers (inlcuding applink id)
2. `/jira-integration/1.0/servers/{INSERT APPLINK ID HERE}/projects` to list JIRA projects available to the logged-in user

Now, per your requirements, I'd hit 1. to get the applink id and then 2. to get the list of the projects. Hope it works with your product versions.

## BONUS - JIRA Proxy

Another nice endpoint is `/plugins/servlet/applinks/proxy`. It allows forwarding simple REST requests to the linked JIRA instances. For example `/plugins/servlet/applinks/proxy?appId={INSERT APPLINK ID HERE}&path=%2Frest%2Fapi%2F2%2Fsearch` will call JIRA's [issue search REST endpoint](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search) and list issues available to the user (as in JIRA search). By "simple request" I mean that only GET and POST HTTP methods are supported in the current version (with POST limited to `application/xml` and `multipart/form-data` content types). The servlet supports both query-string and HTTP-header parameters. Check out the source of the servlet in [plugin's source](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/confluence-jira-plugin) to get more info as I haven't found any online documentation for it.

Using this servlet you can get the projects list as well by requesting `/plugins/servlet/applinks/proxy?appId={INSERT APPLINK ID HERE}&path=%2Frest%2Fapi%2F2%2Fproject`

Servlets's path in the repo is `confluence-jira-plugin/src/main/java/com/atlassian/confluence/plugins/jira/AppLinksProxyRequestServlet.java`, but most of the important stuff is in its base class `confluence-jira-plugin/src/main/java/com/atlassian/confluence/plugins/jira/AbstractProxyServlet.java`